# Get last segment of url without parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ho do I get the last part of a URL segment excluding any URL parameters.

So if I'm on this page:

```
http://example.com/myfolder/mypage.aspx?x=1
```

I want to get:

```
mypage.aspx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something this way:

```js
// The first thing is to strip off the things after query string:
var url = "http://example.com/myfolder/mypage.aspx?x=1";
url = url.split("?")
url = url[0];
// Get the last path:
url = url.split("/");
page = url[url.length-1];
alert(page);
```

The above path will work even if there's no `?` in it.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can just do it oneliner:

```
const lastPart = url.split('?')[0].split('/').at(-1);
```